# Symfony 3 Infinite Scrolling Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to make an infinite Scrolling in Ajax.

I really don't know what is missing.

Html Index:

```
<div class="container">
        <!-- Menu -->

        {% include '::announce/menu.html.twig' %}

        {% for announce in announces|slice(0, 4) %}
        <!-- Announce Preview -->
            {% include '::announce/' ~ game ~ '/preview.html.twig' %}
        {% endfor %}            
</div>

<div id="content"> loop content </div>

<nav id="pagination">
    <p><a href="2">Page 2</a></p>
</nav>


{% endblock %}


{% block javascripts %}    

 <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ias.min.js') }}"></script>                   

{% endblock %}
```

My controller index:

```
    public function indexAction(Request $request, $game)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $announces $em->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Announce')->byGame($game);

        return $this->render('announce/index.html.twig', array(
            'announces' => $announces,
            'game' => $game
        ));
    }
```

With this i have my index page with 4 announce
Now i show you my code for scrolling and adding more announce

Ajax File:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()>= $(document).height()){
                getmoredata();
            }

        })

        function getmoredata() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{ path('announce_page', {'id': '2', 'game': game}) }}",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                        $("#content").append(response.classifiedList);
                        $('#spinner').hide();
                        console.log(response);

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

And this is the controller for page:

```
public function pageAction(Request $request, $game)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $announces = $em->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Announce')->byGame($game);

    $list = $this->renderView('announce/result.html.twig', array(
        'announces' => $announces,
        'game' => $game
    ));

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData(array('classifiedList' => $list));
    return $response;

}
```

Last code, it's the html content for ajax (result.html.twig)

```
    {% for announce in announces|slice(4, 4) %}

    <!-- Affichage Annonce -->

        {% include '::announce/' ~ game ~ '/preview.html.twig' %}

    {% endfor %}
```

For resume, i have my index with 4 announce, when i scroll in bottom, i have a positive ajax request without error. But nothing appear after the 4 announce.

If i go to announce page 2 directly with pagination, i can see 4 other announce. So my routing is working but something don't works in ajax code i think.

Any idea? :)

Thanks

Comment: Hi. I used your code to do my infinite scroll and it works. 
What is your route for pageAction & indexAction ? it's the same route ?
You need to add offset too on your byGame function